# How to use if/else condition in a select in mysql

Tags: mysql, select, if-statement

How can I use an if/else condition on a select statement in mysql?

If Type = "Initial Read", `Select the Initial Column from table_name`
else if Type = "Final Read", `Select the Final Column from table_name`

How should I do this? And what is the right query for this? Do i use case select?

Comment: I think that sort of thing should be handled by the front-end... so the question is: why do you want to do it in raw SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `CASE`

```
SELECT CASE Type
        WHEN "Initial Read" THEN Initial_Column
        WHEN "Final Read" THEN Final_Column
       END column
FROM table_name
WHERE <some condition>
```

Comment: `WHERE` goes after `FROM` and `JOIN`, there's no difference. `CASE` is just a type of expression, no different from calling a function or using arithmetic operators.

Comment: i mean on the select case where do i add it?