# Ho to write a query with IF inside of WHERE clause?

Tags: mysql

I am wondering if its possible to write a query like this:

PHP variables to do comparison: 
    $column2 = A;
    $column3 = null;

```
SELECT * FROM table1 
WHERE col1 = 1
IF(col2 IS NOT NULL)
col2 = $column2
AND 
IF(col3 IS NOT NULL)
col3 = $column3
```

The general idea is to match array of objects against a dynamic filter defined in MySQL table. But i only want to compare the columns which are not null.

Can anyone help or guide me to a better way of doing this?
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use if/else condition in a select in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18927247/how-to-use-if-else-condition-in-a-select-in-mysql)

Comment: You could do a `UNION` of results each a `select` with different `where` clauses as one possible option or you could do multiple `OR` clauses in your `where`

Comment: can you please elaborate further how you mean UNION? or if possible provide  example?

Comment: @jhondano I added an answer below, using multiple conditions in the `WHERE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this could be right

```
SELECT * FROM table1 
WHERE col1 = 1
AND
IFNULL(col2, $column2)=$column2
AND 
IFNULL(col3, $column3)=$column3;
```

but I would create the where clause with php code to dinamically create the SQL statement

Answer (score 0):

Try if this helps

```
SELECT * FROM table1 
WHERE col1 = 1
AND col2 = IIF(col2 IS NOT NULL,$column2,col2)
AND col3 = IIF(col3 IS NOT NULL,$column3,col3)
```